# How to put %random% to a new batch file with a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, random

I want to but this in to an other .bat file

```
echo %random% > test.bat
set /a num= +1 
:repeat1 
set /a num= +1 
echo %random% >> test.bat
if ==100 goto end 
goto repeat1
```

So I have tried with this:

```
echo echo %every%%random%%random%%random%%random% > "output.txt" > test.bat
echo set /a num=%num% +1 >> test.bat
echo :repeat1 >> test.bat
echo set /a num=%num% +1 >> test.bat
echo echo %every%%random%%random%%random%%random% >> "output.txt" >> test.bat
echo if %num%==%amount% goto end >> test.bat
echo goto repeat1 >> test.bat
:end >> test.bat
```

But the %% things don't work (it will put a random nummer but I want to have %random% **in** the **new** .bat file

Comment: So `> "output.txt"` should be in the new batch file literally? you need to escape the `>` by `^>` then, so write `^> "output.txt" > "test.bat"`... the same is true for `>> "output.txt"`, where `>>` becomes `^>^>`...

Comment: "But the %% things don't work " - you don't have any `%%` things. You have `%every%` (which is empty as far as we can see), then `%random%`, another `%random%` and so on. You should have `%%random%%%%random%%%%random%%%%random%%`

Answer (score 1):

you have to escape some chars if you want to write them literally. Most of them are escaped with a caret `^` (`&`,`<`,`>`,`|`). The percent sign is an exception: it is escaped with another percent-sign:`

```
echo %%random%% ^> test.bat
```

But may I suggest another method to write your second bat file (without caring for characters to escape):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=:" %%i in (' findstr /n /c:":: Start of Second ::" "%~dpnx0"') do set start=%%i
more +%start% "%~dpnx0" >test.bat
call test.bat
echo -------
type test.txt
echo -------

goto :eof
:: Start of Second ::
@echo off
echo %random% >test.txt
set /a num=0 
:repeat1 
  set /a num+=1 
  echo %random% >>test.txt
  if %num%==10 goto :eof
goto .repeat1
```

The `for` is used to determine the start line of the data to be written,
`more +n` writes the file (`"~dpnx0"` is the currently running batchfile) by skipping the first `n` lines.

Pro: no need to escape anything - just write the data as it should be outputted.

Contra: only one "second file" possible; only static text possible.