# Is there a way that i can output a %variable% in a batch file without expressing its value?

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way that i can output(export) a %variable% in a batch file without expressing its value?

For instance, if i want random numbers in output.bat files i could do:

```
>output.bat( 
set var1=%random% 
echo var1
pause
)`
```

Now, if i open the output file, you might think i will find a random number each time a open it, right? Wrong, because when i output the variable it doesn't export the var itself but its value. How to 'solve' this?

I've tried a really arcaic way that works in CMD, but apparently not in the in anything.bat

This:

```
set test=random
echo %%test%%>output.bat
```

I would love your help guys, i'm trying to create a simple script and this is the only part that i haven't managed yet. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: So you want your `output.bat` file to contain `set var1=%random%` literally, right? what's wrong with `set var1=%%random%%`?

Comment: It worked, Thank you.
PS.: Can you explain me why?

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36678248/2152082)

Comment: When parsing a *batch file*, the command interpreter scans for `%` signs to find environment variables (like `%Variable%`) or script arguments (`%1`, `%2`,...) and to replace them by the respective values; a stand-alone `%%` sequence is simply replaced by a literal `%` during this process (by "stand-alone" I mean something like `some_text%%more_text`; a string like `%Var1%%Var2%` is not what I call "stand-alone", as this contains two variables); this is also the reason why you have to double the `%`-signs for `for` variables in batch files (`for %%I in (*) do`)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what your desired `output.bat` should look like.

This will create a file called `output.bat` with just `%random%`:

`somebatfile.bat`

```
>>output.bat (
set "var1=%%random%%"
echo %var1%
)
```

.

`output.bat`

```
%random%
```

This will create an `output.bat` file with two lines, and I *think* might be what you're looking for.

`somebatfile.bat`

```
set "outtxt=set var1=%%random%%"
echo %outtxt%> output.bat
set "outtxt=echo %%var1%%"
echo %outtxt%>> output.bat
```

.

`output.bat`

```
set var1=%random%
echo %var1%
```

Comment: You cannot escape `%` with `^` in a batch file (this works only directly in command prompt, I think); you need to state `%%` to get a literal `%`; note that the OP tagged the question with [tag:batch-file]...

Comment: @aschipfl Oops!  You are correct.  I edited my answer accordingly.  And you got it right in your comments before I posted my (incorrect) answer.