# How do I create a batch file with a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

How do I create a batch file that creates a custom batch file? I was wondering how to so I can make a certain application on my computer. Thank you. :)

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36678248/2152082)

Comment: Assuming you're talking about windows batch files, see a [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954719/how-can-a-batch-script-do-the-equivalent-of-cat-eof) question and answer. This post explains how to create _any_ file with _any_ contents from a batch file. Having said that, batch files are really not well suited to that kind of work. On the other hand, you can use `echo "content" > batch_file.bat` to create first line and then `echo "more content" >> batch_file.bat` to append to that. Batch files are not special in any way, they just have a `.bat` extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a .bat file with this:

```
echo echo hi > "{path}\mybat.bat"
echo echo pause >> "{path}\mybat.bat"
```